# Glass pan for sourdough?

Tags: sourdough, pan, glass

Can I successfully use a lidded round glass baking dish do to bake a sourdough bread? I have not made sourdough before. Just need to know if I really need to buy a cast iron dutch oven for this.

Comment: I gave up on using enamelled cast iron, and switched to a loaf tin, because I want slices for sandwiches.  I do the final prove in the tin.  It's also easier than trying to drop the loaf perfectly into a cast iron dish.  So you don't need to spend the money to try it

Comment: You don't need *any* special pan for sourdough. You might want a particular sort of pan for a particular method of baking sourdough, but sourdough is perfectly happy to be baked in any number of ways - on a baking sheet, in a loaf pan, etc... I currently use a silicone and/or a non-stick aluminum pan, and cover with foil and/or a beaten-to-fit takeout container for the first part of baking, which works better for me than any number of messier steam producing techniques. And I get normal slices that fit in the toaster.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your baking technique.  If you're using [the dutch oven technique where you heat up the vessel](https://www.pantrymama.com/dutch-oven-sourdough-bread/) to 450F before depositing the dough into it, no.  Adding cold dough to hot glass is likely to result in the glass cracking or shattering.

If you're putting the glass and dough in together, cold, it'll work fine.

Note that you don't really need a vessel of any kind.  You can just make a freeform loaf and put it on a baking sheet.

Comment: If it's borosilicate glass (e.g. old or non-American Pyrex) it will be fine.

Comment: That's pretty hard to get your hands on these days.

Comment: that depends where you live (or rather where the OP does). Both the large supermarkets near me stock proper borosilicate pyrex cookware. And it's pretty robust so tends to get handed down

Comment: Really?  I didn't think they were even making it anymore.

Comment: The brand is owned by different manufacturers in different places, and the European owners didn't take the cheap option on the core products. There's another European manufacturer of borosilicate kitchenware as well, probably Arcoroc in France though I can't remember for certain

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it's big enough you can bake bread in a glass dish. It's not about it being sourdough, other types of bread use the dish method. Glass may take a bit longer to heat up, but it shouldn't make any real difference in the end result.